# Substitution using g++ preprocessor makes link error

Tags: c++, linker, g++, preprocessor

Do you guys know why below code makes a link error with g++? (not a compile error)
I'm curious about how g++ works here

**Brief description of the purpose**

- main uses class AAA
- class AAA uses class BBB  (BBB is a library)
- try to substitute class BBB into fake one in main function using preprocessor

**File structure**

```sh
project
|-- src
|   |-- main.cpp
|   |-- aaa.h
|   |-- aaa.cpp
|-- lib
    |-- bbb.h
    |-- bbb.cpp
```

**Source files**

1. main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define BBB BBB_substitution
#include "../lib/bbb.h"
#undef BBB

class BBB {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Fake: hello world" << std::endl;
    }
};

#include "aaa.h"

int main() {
    AAA aaa;
    aaa.print();
}
```

2. aaa.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../lib/bbb.h"

class AAA {
public:
    BBB bbb;
    void print();
};
```

3. aaa.cpp

```cpp
#include "aaa.h"

void AAA::print() {
    bbb.print();
}
```

4. bbb.h

```cpp
#pragma once

class BBB {
public:
    void print();
};
```

5. bbb.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "bbb.h"

void BBB::print() {
    std::cout << "Real: hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You have 3 translation units and they use 2 different definitions of `BBB`. One has `print` defined _inline_, the other one _not inline_. Not sure whether you are allowed to mix them.

Comment: Here is a [similar case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mt2eyLF1jf3Ouyec). It does not generate an error, but a different `BBB::print` is called depending on whether you link `bbb.o` or not. I guess the behavior is undefined according to the C++ Stnadard (but am not entirely sure about it).

Comment: ODR violation so UB

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ODR violations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) in the code. The rule says that the class definition needs to have *the same sequence of tokens* in every translation units. Even if one name is different, the ODR is broken and the behavior is undefined.

The translation unit `main.cpp` is compiled with:

```
class BBB {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Fake: hello world" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The translation unit `bbb.cpp` and `aaa.cpp` are compile with:

```
class BBB {
public:
    void print();
};
```

The token after `print()` is `{` in `main.cpp`, while in `bbb.cpp` and in `aaa.cpp` the next token after `print()` is `;`. Only this is enough for ODR to be broken and for the behavior of your code is undefined.

To do what you want to do, *link* your code with a different `BBB::print` implementation:

```
c++ main.cpp aaa.cpp bbb.cpp       -o normal_executable
c++ main.cpp aaa.cpp bbb_mock.cpp  -o test_code_executable
```

Where `bbb_mock.cpp` "mocks"/implements the interface that is exposed in `bbb.h`.